# What is the best open source common lisp implementation that works with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lisp, common-lisp

I have started working my way through Practical Common Lisp and am looking for a Common LISP implementation that works on Eclipse. It would be nice if it had some kind of IDE integration besides the editor and the REPL (although I'm not sure what that would be). Also, I have Linux, Windows, and OS X, although my primary workstation is a Mac, so OS X support is preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cusp is an awesome plug-in. You do not necessarily need to use the SBCL implementation.

Here is the [group](http://groups.google.com/group/cusp-development).

The repository has moved to [here](http://groups.google.com/group/cusp-development/browse_thread/thread/68e966593da8fad3#).

Comment: Thanks, I came across Cusp but never found the Google group.

Answer (score 2):

Clozure CL offers a MacOS-specific IDE. Not sure whether it's what you want...

Answer (score 1):

The [Cusp plugin page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-lispcusp/index.html) recommends [SBCL](http://sbcl.sourceforge.net/).